# How can I find first principal component (and loadings) fast without using covariance matrix?

Tags: julia, pca

I have a matrix $X$ and I would like to find its first principal component and the corresponding loadings. I would like to do this without computing the covariance matrix of $X$. How can I do so?

This is the standard version, which uses the eigendecomposition of the covariance matrix.

```
using LinearAlgebra: eigen
using Statistics: mean

function find_principal_component(X)
    n = size(X, 1)
    B = X .- mapslices(mean, X, dims=[1])     # Center columns of X
    evalues, V = eigen(B'B / (n - 1))         # EigenDecomposition of Covariance Matrix     
    PC = V[:, argmax(evalues)]                # Grab principal component and compute loading
    return B * PC, PC
end
```

Alternatively, one could use the power method, which still uses the covariance matrix

```
function power_method(X, niter=50)
    pc = randn(size(X, 2))
    pc /= norm(pc)
    M = X'X
    for i in 1:niter
        pc = M * pc
        pc /= norm(pc)
    end
    return X * pc, pc
end
```

I would like something like the power method, but without needing to compute the covariance matrix, which can be quite costly.

## Possible solution

I noticed something interesting. Let `r_t` be the principal component vector at time `t`. The idea of the power method is to start with a random `r_t` and multiply it by `X' X` many times to stretch it towards the principal component. In other words `r_{t+1} = X' X r_t`
Once we have the principal component `r_t` then the loadings are simply `\ell_t = X r_t`. This means we can write `r_{t+1} = X^\top \ell_t`
One could therefore start with `r_t` and `\ell_t` initialized randomly and then do

```
r_{t+1} = normalize(X^\top \ell_t)\\
\ell_{t+1} = X r_{t+1}
```

Comment: Maybe post on [SciComp](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you may find singular value decompositions more useful for this.

The definition of the singular value decomposition is

```
B = U Σ V'
```

This means that

```
B'B = V Σ² V'
```

As a result, you code can avoid the computation of `B'B`. More importantly, the singular values are always real and thus you don't have to worry about whether `B'B` will be exactly symmetric.

Even better, `Arpack.svds` allows you to compute just the largest few singular values.

Here is a version of your code that uses SVD instead of eigen decomposition:

```
using LinearAlgebra: eigen
using Statistics: mean
using Arpack: svds

function find_principal_component(X)
    n = size(X, 1)
    # Center columns of X
    B = X .- mapslices(mean, X, dims=[1]) 
    # Decomposition of Covariance Matrix
    svd,_ = svds(B / (n - 1), nsv=1)        
    # Grab principal component and compute loading
    PC = svd.V[:, 1]
    return B * PC, PC
end
```

Running this on a large sparse matrix (100k x 1k, 1M non-zeros) gives this speed:

```
julia> @time find_principal_component(sprandn(100_000, 1_000, 0.01))
 25.529426 seconds (18.45 k allocations: 3.015 GiB, 0.02% gc time)
([0.014242904195824286, 0.10635817357717596, -0.010142643763158442, ...])
```

and on a large non-sparse example (1M x 100 entries):

```
julia> @time find_principal_component(randn(1_000_000, 100))
  4.922949 seconds (1.31 k allocations: 2.280 GiB, 0.02% gc time)
([-0.06629858174095249, 0.6996443876327108, -1.1783642870384952, ...])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using KrylovKit.jl. Specifically, `eigsolve(X, howmany=1, which=:LM])` will give you the eigen value with largest magnitude and the associated eigenvector. Docs are at https://jutho.github.io/KrylovKit.jl/stable/man/eig/